# Continue execution after WP REST API response

Tags: php, plugin-development, rest-api, optimization, endpoints

I am trying to extend the Wordpress REST API with an endpoint that takes Zoom webhooks. Zoom requires a response within 3 seconds or will blacklist your endpoint address, but the processing that I want to do when I receive a webhook takes longer than 3 seconds.

What options do I have for returning a response from the WP REST API immediately but then carrying on execution?

Ideas:

- [`exec()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) a child process in the background then return the response (but this might be a security risk)
- Write a flag to the filesystem then return the response. A regular `cron` job will spot the flag and do the processing (but this will result in a delay in the process being done depending on how frequently the `cron` job is scheduled)

For non-WP scenarios I've seen solutions proposed that use [`fastcgi_finish_request()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fastcgi-finish-request.php) but I'm not sure how I could `return` a result from my callback function using this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do in WordPress is to dispatch a non blocking new request to itself, and then resume the response.

Something like this:

```
$action_name = 'sample_action';
$url = add_query_arg(
    [
        'action' => $action_name,
        'nonce'  => \wp_create_nonce( $action_name ),
    ],
    admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
);

$body = [ 'your data' ];

// trigger a non-blocking request.
wp_remote_post(
    $url,
    [
        'timeout'   => 0.01,
        'blocking'  => false,
        'body'      => $body,
        'cookies'   => $_COOKIE,
        'sslverify' => apply_filters( 'https_local_ssl_verify', false ),
    ]
);

// return rest response and free the request.
return rest_ensure_response( 'success' );
```

And then, you add the usual callbacks to handle the admin ajax call:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $action_name, 'so_377405_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_' . $action_name, 'so_377405_callback' );

function so_377405_callback() {

    // Don't lock up other requests while processing.
    session_write_close();

    if ( ! isset( $_REQUEST['nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST['nonce'] ), 'sample_action' ) ) {
        wp_die();
    }

    // ... do stuff

    wp_die();

}
```

Is 3 years too late for a response?

Comment: By no means is it too late, I found myself asking the same question relatively recently!